# refresh scope after data service add is finished

Tags: angularjs

I ask the question short time before...but i think it was to complex.
So i try to ask it in an better way here.

i have a mysql database and i use php files to add, edit and get data.

the example works fine, but i am searching a way to refresh my $scope.projects after adding (add()-function new data to the mysql database). are there any ideas?

i dont pass any data to the save.php yet...its static at this time.

```
test.factory('DataService', function ($http, $log) {

    return {

        getProjects: function ( callback ) {
            $http.get('php/data.php').success( callback );
        },

        addProject: function ( ) {
            $http.get('php/save.php');
        }


    };

});


test.controller('projects', function ( $scope, DataService ) {

    DataService.getProjects(function( results ){
        $scope.projects =  results;
    });

    $scope.add = function ( ) {
        DataService.addProject();
    };

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want get data from database, after adding, you can easly push new added object to $scope.projects.

Some code:

```
 $scope.add = function (newProject) {
        DataService.addProject().then(function(){
           $scope.projects.push(newProject);
        });
    };
```

And adjust your factory:

```
   addProject: function (newProject) {
        $http.post('php/save.php').then(function(successResult){ 
             ...
        }, function (errorResult) {
           ...
        });
    }
```

Comment: the then function als fires when there is an mysql error? isnt it better to get data from sql to see that its realy joined in?

Comment: No. then() function calls after operation complete and contain two parameters (callback function). First callback fun - success result, second - error result.
I updated my answer with example.

Comment: nice. thats what i need ;-)

Comment: how can i send the form data with get? i how must i handle them in the php?

Answer (score 2):

You have to return promise:

```
return $http.get('php/save.php')
```

And than in add function:

```
DataService.addProject().than(function(){
    DataService.getProjects(function( results ){
        $scope.projects =  results;
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
$scope.add = function () {
  DataService.addProject({"name":this.name}).then(function () {
    DataService.getProjects(function(results){
       $scope.projects =  results;
    });
  });
};
```

factory:

```
addProject: function (data) {
   return $http.post('php/save.php',data)
}
```

Is this the right way to send the data or is there a smarter one?